# Activator.CreateInstance MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection

I have a class in a c# dll with the following class

```
public class RequiredTask : Base.BaseObject
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public RequiredTask() 
        : base()
    { }

}
```

Which inherits from this class

```
public class BaseObject : IBaseObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy
    public DateTime? CreatedOn
    public string CreatedBy 

    public BaseObject() { }

}
```

Then the UI, is a VB.Net Winform, this form is going to be a base form and is generic so it can work with all the types from the c# library, and it has a new button that needs to instanciate the new type of whatever T is and pass it to a form which will be used to edit T.

this is the form code

```
Public Class Search(Of T As Library.Base.BaseObject)

        Private Sub btnNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
            If MyBase.OpenFormName <> "" Then App.mfrmMDI.OpenForm(MyBase.OpenFormName, DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T), New Object()), T))
        End Sub

End Class
```

But I get this error Constructor on type 'Library.Production.RequiredTask' not found. when it reaches

```
DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T), New Object()), T)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting the exception because there is no matching constructor on the type that takes a single parameter of type `object`.

Change the call to:

```
DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T)), T)
```

This should automatically call the default constructor, which is the one you have defined.

Comment: changing new Object() to Nothing doesnt actually compile, with an overloaded resolution error

Comment: @user1584413 - Updated the answer to use the proper overload to call the default constructor.