# System.MissingMethodException error

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "DotNetOpenAuth.dll");
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
Type type = assembly.GetType("DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.UserAgentClient");

if (type != null) 
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("ProcessUserAuthorization");

    if (methodInfo != null)
    {
        object result = null;
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        if (parameters.Length == 0)
        {
            result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
        }
        else
        {
            object parametersArray = new object[] { "One", "Two" };

            result = methodInfo.Invoke(methodInfo, parametersArray);
        }
    }
}
```

On the line

```
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

I  am getting an error

> System.MissingMethodException

Can anyone help me to look into the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activator.CreateInstance MissingMethodException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957097/activator-createinstance-missingmethodexception)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see "Exceptions" section):

> No matching public constructor was found.

Thus, you either need public parameterless constructor in `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.UserAgentClient`, or you have to use another [`CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload and provide parameters.